# Segfault - invalid pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm attaching a snippet. I have ommitted a lot. If needed I will attach more:

```
 unsigned char *datap = malloc (MAXSIZE);
 unsigned char *datapor = datap;
 //Here Im cutting a lot
 while( (direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
 {
   datap = datapor;
 }
//this line gives me exception 
free(datap);
```

gcc shows:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/xf/xf/unzipper: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00002aaaab0b0108 ***
```

Comment: You seem to be cutting to much. The code you show should not mess up the memory management. You might like to show each operation on `datapor`and `datap` between the call to `malloc()` and the one to `free()`.

Comment: valgrind valgrind valgrind!

Answer (score 2):

You reassign `datap` in your while loop, so when you call `free`, `datap` no longer points to the allocated memory.

(I am assuming that the value of `datapor` changes in the omitted code.)

Comment: But datapor is set to the initial value of datap, which is the value returned from malloc, and never subsequently changed.  So all the while loop does is repeatedly set datap to the same value, which is the value returned from malloc.

Comment: @Nigel Assigning the same value repeatedly doesn't make sense, so I assumed that the value of `datapor` changes in the omitted code.

Comment: You may well be right, but IMHO that assumption should be part of the answer. As it stands your answer appears to refer to the code as shown, and as such is simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your malloc could have fail because of the macro MAXSIZE. If you have not enough memory this could fail.

Start to check if datap = malloc(MAXSIZE) is a viable pointer.

```
unsigned char *datap = malloc (MAXSIZE);
if (datap == NULL)
    return -1; //malloc failed
```

Comment: Whilst checking the return value of malloc is sound advice, free(NULL) is perfectly valid so it wouldn't explain the error.

Comment: -1 for recommending `NULL`-check of `free()`, not needed. Also the code uses weirdly spelled `If` keyword. :)

Comment: edited. I was in hurry for the If. But right for the free(NULL)